# What is wrong with this derivation of $\frac{d}{dx}x^2$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We have simple function:
$$Y = X^2$$

Writing $X^2$ as: $X^2 = \underbrace{X+X+X+...+X}_{X \text{ times}}$

We can write above equation as:

$$ Y = \underbrace{X+X+X+...+X}_{X \text{ times}}$$

Differentiating with respect to $X$, we get:

$$
\frac{dY}{dX} = \underbrace{1+1+1+1+........+1}_{X \text{ times}}\\
\frac{dY}{dX} =X
$$

Since it is known that result must be: 
$$\frac{dY}{dX}= 2X$$

I just want to know what is wrong with the above derivation.

Comment: $X = 1.5$ times?

Comment: what do you want to say..?

Comment: What do **you** want to say? What is $X +  X+ \cdots +X (X$ times) when $X = 1.5$?

Comment: I understood your point. But why above derivation is incorrect ?

Comment: Writing $X^2 = X+X+\cdots +X$ only make sense when $X$ is a positive integer. So you cannot differentiate on both side (the right side is just not defined when $X$ is not an integer, so there is no way you can take limit, which is necessary when doing differentiation.

Comment: It got your point. But what above result indicate then ? Can we interpret above result ?

Comment: The above example indicate that you have to be very careful when writing $\cdots\cdots$.

Comment: Can I say :  function can be differentiated only if it is  continuous. Writing $X^2 = X+X+....+X$ would discrete(-ize) the above function.

Comment: You forgot that not only do the $X$'s increase, but the _number_ of $X$'s also increase. That means that the derivative isn't simply $1+1+\cdots +1$ $X$ times.

Comment: You cannot differentiate both sides of an **equality**. Because the slopes of LHS and RHS may not be equal. And this is an equality because it is not true for all $X$s.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal But it is not an equation. It is an _equality_ of functions. Of course it is true for all $X$, that's how $Y$ was _defined_, after all.

Comment: I agree that it is an equality of functions, but not with that it is true for all $X$s. See, for example, $0.5$. There is nothing as $0.5$ times. @Arthur

Answer (score 8):

Let's say we play along, just to see what happens. We have
$$
X^2 = X+X+X+\cdots +X\tag{$X$ times}
$$
as well as
$$
(X+h)^2 = X + X + \cdots + X + h+h+\cdots + h \tag{$X+h$ times}
$$
Now, by applying the definition of derivative, we get
$$
\frac {dY}{dX} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(X+h)^2 - X^2}{h}\\
= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\overbrace{X+X+\cdots+X}^{X+h - X = h\text{ times}} + \overbrace{h + h +\cdots + h}^{X+h\text{ times}}}{h}\\
= \lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{\overbrace{X+X+\cdots+X}^{h\text{ times}}}{h} + \frac{\overbrace{h + h +\cdots + h}^{X+h\text{ times}}}{h}\right)\\
= \lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{hX}{h} + \frac{(X+h)h}{h}\right)\\
= \lim_{h\to 0} (X + X+h) = 2X
$$
I still don't approve (although I do admit it was a fun exercise), but just like pretending $\frac{dY}{dX}$ is an actual fraction that can be simplified gives the correct chain rule, this does give the correct result in the end.

Comment: Thanks Arthur. It is wonderful derivation...

Comment: by op's definition of function, $X$ is restricted to integers. So the function is not continuous. This means IMO you can't apply $f(x+h)$ where h is arbitrarily small real number with your definition of derivative.

Comment: @Arthur Fighting fire with fire :)

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz Did you notice where I said "Let's say we play along"? That was the exact moment I stopped caring about pesky things such as "this doesn't make sense". Did you also notice where I said "I still don't approve"? That's where I say to exactly people like you (and those who might not know that this is wrong) that "You are of course right that this is wrong".

Answer (score 2):

$$Y = X^2$$

Wrong: $X^2$ as : $X^2 = X+X+X+...........+X$ $(n\,times, n=2, \implies n X )$ in this case,

Right:  $X^2$ as : $X^2 = X * X * X * .....X$ $(n \,times, n=2 ,\implies X^n )$ in this case.

Although multiplication is repeated addition and exponentiation is repeated multiplication, they should not be confused as to their original operative application.

Comment: thanks @Narasimham for explaining in different context

Comment: You are wrong, @Narasimham, $x^2$ is indeed $x+\cdots +x$, $x$ times for natural $x$: $x+\cdots+x=x(1+\cdots+1)=x\cdot x$.